# Android - ListView - Output value in listview to screen

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a SQLite Database that contains the following information

```
--------------------------------
Account_Name    Account_Balance
-------------------------------- 
Savings         1000.00

Checking        1000.00
```

I have the item being output to a Listview.  My question is how do I get my OnItemClick to properly tell me the value that was selected?  When I click Savings, I want "Savings" to appear through a Toast.  When I tried output, I could only output the item position. I don't want the position in the listview, I am more interested in the String value.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        /*What do I need to code here to just have the value outputted*/        

        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //toast.show();
    }
```

CODE:
main_menu_activity.java

```
public class main_menu_activity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
DatabaseHandler db;
ArrayList<Account> account_details;
ListView accountList;
int num;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_activity);
    accountList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.accountListView);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    displayListView();

    // Empty Account table
    //db.deleteFromAccountTable();

    accountList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    num = 1;
}

// MENU //
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu_activity, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// MENU //
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // take appropriate action for each action item clicked
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_add_new:
        {
            // perform add new item action
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setMessage("Enter account details:");

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            // Set an EditText view
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setHint("Account Name");
            layout.addView(input);

            final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
            input2.setHint("Account Balance");
            layout.addView(input2);

            alert.setView(layout);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    if (input.getText().toString() != null)
                    {
                        // Create empty Account
                        Account temp_account;
                        temp_account = new Account();

                        // Save information to SQLiteDatabase
                        temp_account.setAccountName(input.getText().toString());
                        temp_account.setAccountBalance(Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString()));

                        // Add temp account
                        db.addAccount(temp_account);
                        displayListView();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    // Output to logcat
                    /*ArrayList<Account> allAccounts = db.getAllAccounts();
                    for (Account account: allAccounts)
                    {
                        Log.d("Output", Integer.toString(account.getAccountID()));
                        Log.d("Output", account.getAccountName());
                        Log.d("Output", Double.toString(account.getAccountBalance()));
                    }*/
                    // cancel
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });

            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
        default:
        {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    /* CODE TO OUTPUT SELECTED LISTVIEW VALUE */
}

// DISPLAY ACCOUNT LISTVIEW //
public void displayListView()
{
    account_details = new ArrayList<Account>();
    account_details = db.getAllAccounts();
    accountList.setAdapter(new ListViewBaseAdapter(account_details,this));
}
}
```

listview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#00628B"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#00628B"
    android:textSize="22dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to have a custom adapter (and layout file) for the row and then add handler for each View in that row.

[Vogella has some awesome tutorials so instead of regurgitating them I will point you there.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the name, then why don't you try something like this:

1. Define an XML layout that contains a row, probably a TextView for each.
2. Put this code in a custom adapter.
3. Set the id for the value that contains the savings/checking name, let's say `android:id="@+id/accountType`
4. Find that view in the `onItemClicked`, and get the text.

The code looks like:

```
String type=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.accountType)).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your own custom adapter for that. So you can just attach `OnClickListener`s at the `getView()` method to every needed View (TextView in your case). Then inside this listener do the following:

```
View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView myView = (TextView) v;
        Toast.makeText(context, myView.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```